# Spring Cloud Stream - Send and receive synchronized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

In my spring boot rest controller, I'm using StreamBridge for sending a message to the rabbitMQ server with something like

```
streamBridge.send("consumer-in-0", "hello world");
```

Is there a way to do a `send and wait the response` ?

Comment: Late to the party, but did you get any response to that?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as I said, late to the party, but there seems to be a way. simply you can make the producer synchronous, this can be done in application.properties as such:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.functionName-out-0.producer.sync=true
```

The same configuration was originally working for the MessageChannel pre Spring cloud function, but as I understand the underlying functionality is already the same